# Accessing Apache Server from the internet

Tags: apache, redirect, permissions

I have installed Apache on Xubuntu and I am have a problem accessing it from the internet. 
If I access it via localhost I can reach the home page plus pages in the subdirectory.  How if I access it from the internet I can get the home page but nothing else.  When I type in the subdirectory and page, no links at this point, It either never leaves the home page or gets rerouted back to it.

I have no .htaccess files in place, I have tried adding an alias and  entries in the conf file and I have checked ownership and permissions.  I have gone as far as wiping the machine and starting with the same results.

I feel like it is going to be a case of missing something simple but I cannot think of what.  The log files have indicated that an IP tried to access the subdirectory but shows no error in doing so.  When typed into the URL the /Directory/Index.html shows in the address bar but it displays the home page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is contained either in your apache.conf file or your firewall. I would have a good look at your apache.conf to see if there is anything restricting access to your sub-directories.

Comment: disabling the firewall is one of the first things I tried.  If it is in the apache.conf I am not sure what is causing it.  The file is pretty much default.  Is there anything that needs changed by default to allow viewing in subdirectories?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use default http port (80), so long story short www.abc.com without explicit port number, you must allow this on your server because 80 is privileged on most system, this could be a problem

Comment: Port 80 seems to be fine.  The home page at the root level comes back fine.  It is just anything in subdirectories that does not show.